# Select repository via the REST API

Tags: graphdb

I'm trying to use the new embedded visualisation feature. I have an iframe that points to the graphdb server with url in the form :

> http://localhost:7200/graphs-visualizations?uri=[...]&embedded

That works fine, but only for the default or previously selected repository. I can't find a way to select repositories without having to manually go to http://localhost:7200/

It seems that the repository selection is stored in a cookie, and that the `X-GraphDB-Repository` HTTP header is available, but nothing seems to work with iframes.

Is there a way to select repositories through url ? `&repository=` would be perfect.

More detail : we have an app with N "studies" backed with N repositories (with SPARQL queries), when a user selects a study, then an uri, we want to display a Visual Graph iframe. That works for the default or previously selected repository, but when she go to another study, we need a way to transparently update/select the repository in the Workbench app.

The only solution we see for the moment is to use a proxy that will set the cookie on the fly. But that seems overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally decided to configure a nginx proxy workaround. It works well, but a `?repository=` query feature is definitely missing.

```
map $arg_repository $repo_cookie {
  "~^(?<repo>[0-9a-f]{32})$" "com.ontotext.graphdb.repository7200=$repo";
}

server {
  listen 7200;
  server_name localhost;

  location / {
    add_header Set-Cookie $repo_cookie;
    proxy_pass http://graphdb:7200;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

GraphDB Workbench has two mechanisms to control the current selected repository. To illustrate this open Setup > Repositories pages and check:

(1) the "Connect repository" icon (the first option in the Repository list) controls the current selected repository by storing it in the local store. Check [what is the difference between local storage and a cookie.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies)

(2) the "Set as default repository" icon (the last option in the repository list) controls the default server repository. When a default repository is selected the server assumes to which repository to dispatch all HTTP requests like linked data publishing or like in your case the Visual Graph.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can't set local storage through an iframe either. I want to embed the visualisation in an app that maintain multiple repositories, so that the user don't have to manually go to another domain and manually select the repository.

Comment: Do you want to expose multiple repositories controlled by the user with a single Visual Graph?

Comment: We have an app with N "studies" backed with N repositories (with SPARQL queries), when a user selects a study, then an uri, we want to display a Visual Graph iframe. That works for the default selected repository, but when she go to another study, we need a way to transparently update/select the repository in the Workbench app.